# Is there a way to make a UISegmentedControl button different sizes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl with 2 items.

Is there a way to make the left item a bit larger than the right item?

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:symbol,@"+", nil]];
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [segmentedControl setWidth:45 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [segmentedControl setWidth:20 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,30);
        segmentedControl.momentary = NO;
        [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

        self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes you can do this:-

```
    [*yoursegmentcontrolobjectname* setWidth:45 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [*yoursegmentcontrolobjectname* setWidth:15 forSegmentAtIndex:1];   

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:symbol,@"+", nil]];
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,30);
        segmentedControl.momentary = NO;
        [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

        self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

add these two lines now then it will work

```
        [segmentedControl setWidth:45 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [segmentedControl setWidth:20 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: I tried using setWidth:forSegmentIndex but not having any luck. I am putting a UISegmentedControl in a UINavigationBar as the titleview

Comment: I think you problem will be solved by using the edited answer.

Comment: Works! Thanks for the follow up. Tricky beast.

Answer (score 9):

Sure. You can use [`-setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:) (be sure to do it after you set the segmented control's bounds/frame), or just change the width in your interface file (it seems this doesn't work in the navigation bar, only elsewhere):

[image]

Comment: I tried using setWidth:forSegmentIndex but not having any luck. I am putting a UISegmentedControl in a UINavigationBar as the titleview

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: Have you tried doing it directly in Interface Builder?

Comment: See my updated question. I am doing it programmatically because I am adding it to my UINavBar

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: Unfortunately I see the same result. I don't think you can do this.

Comment: The UINavigationBar is a red herring. See gypsa or my answer below. The issue is calling setWidth BEFORE you set the frame.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Still a bug that it doesn't work in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to adjust the size of the segment element to its contents use this BOOL property:

apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent

and set it to YES (default is NO)

Answer (score 4):

### iOS 6 Update

In iOS 5 and lower we must call `setWidth: forSegmentAtIndex:` after the frame and other display properties were set to have it work. This is corrected in iOS 6 and the order no longer matters.

Answer (score 2):

Place the your `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` call after the your `setFrame:' call. That should do the trick. Most of the time ordering doesn't matter to much in Cocoa Touch, just so long as everything is done before the end of the code. In this case, ordering does matter.

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:symbol,@"+", nil]];
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,30);
        [segmentedControl setWidth:45 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [segmentedControl setWidth:20 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        segmentedControl.momentary = NO;
        [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

        self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```